# Multiple next / previous

Tags: next-post-link, previous-post-link

One of my custom post types requieres multiple next/precious post titles buttons for usability issues. Does anyone know how to get this working?

Example:

**LATEST POST (Today)**

[previous post title] - [previous post title] - [previous post title]

**YESTERDAY POST**

[next post title] - [previous post title] - [previous post title]

**LAST POST**

[next post title] - [next post title] - [next post title]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should try [Ambrosite Next/Previous Post Link Plus](http://www.ambrosite.com/plugins/next-previous-post-link-plus-for-wordpress). It gives you the option of displaying multiple next or previous links among a number of other great options.